# How to get child elements that descend directly from parent with Jsoup?

Tags: android, jsoup

U use Jsoup to fetch a website. The website has multiple div classes such as:

```
<div class="itemcategories">
Category: <a id="cat_result_7_newamerican" class="category" rel="newamerican" href="/search?cflt=newamerican&amp;find_loc=willowbrook%2C+IL">American (New)</a>
</div>

<div class="itemcategories">
Categories: 
<a id="cat_result_6_breakfast_brunch" class="category" rel="breakfast_brunch" href="/search?cflt=breakfast_brunch&amp;find_loc=willowbrook%2C+IL">Breakfast & Brunch</a>, 
<a id="cat_result_6_tradamerican" class="category" rel="tradamerican" href="/search?cflt=tradamerican&amp;find_loc=willowbrook%2C+IL">American (Traditional)</a>
</div>
```

and so on.

If I use the following query selector:

```
categories = doc.select("div[class=itemcategories] > a[class=category]");
```

each child element that descend directly from *div class="itemcategories"* parent is stored in the next index of the categories Elements object. So I have no way to determine which children belong to which parents. Is there a way to 'concatenate' all the children from each div class and save them in a separate indices of the Elements object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about doing it in two steps?

```
Elements parents = doc.select("div.itemcategories");
for (Element parent : parents)
{
    Elements categories = parent.select("a.category");
    // do something with categories
}
```

Note use of `.foo` instead of `[class=foo]` selector syntax.

**N.B.** I'm not terribly familiar with jsoup's API so this code may not be exactly correct.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. It helped me to create another, one step solution.

Answer (score 0):

In additon to @Matt Ball solution I have figured out one step solution:

```
// Select the parent's
categories = doc.select(".itemcategories");
```

and then simply use children() method to get the children and text() method to get the desired text:

```
categories.get(counter).children().text();
```

Comment: Well, I wouldn't exactly call that one step `:P`